# AJAX sends all fields in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have a HTML file that calls a CGI script. When I click logout button, POST method sends all the fields. Is this a known bug?

Here is my Javascript code:

```
var request = null, session = null;
    function postEscape(val) {
        return encodeURIComponent(val).replace(/%20/g, "+")
    }



    function submit_logout() {
var request=null
if( !document.form.loggedIn.checked ) return
logout = new XMLHttpRequest()
logout.open("POST", "client.cgi", true /* asynchronous? */ )
logout.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
console.log("action=logout&session=" + postEscape(document.form.session.value)+"&host="+postEscape(document.form.host.value)+"&port="+postEscape(document.form.port.value))
logout.send("action=logout&session=" + postEscape(document.form.session.value)+"&host="+postEscape(document.form.host.value)+"&port="+postEscape(document.form.port.value)+"&action=logout")
form.loggedIn.checked = false

}
```

This is what I see in POST data:

username=&password=&host=somehost.com&port=6700&action=logout&display=++++&session=

and here is my form

```
<body>
<form name = "form">
<input name="username" size="25" type="text">username<br>
<input name="password" size="25" type="text">password<br>
<input name="host" size="25" type="text">host<br>
<input name="port" size="25" type="text">port<br>
<input name="login" value="Login" type="button" onclick="submit_login()"><input        type="checkbox" name="loggedIn" id = "loggedIn" onclick="this.checked=!this.checked">

<input name="action" value="logout" type="submit" onClick="submit_logout()"><br>
<textarea name="display" rows="24" cols="68">    </textarea><br>
<input type="hidden" name="session" value="">
<input name="message" size="64" maxlength="64" type="text"><input name="send"     value="send" type="button" onClick = "send()"><p></p>
  </form>
```

Comment: Are you getting different values from the console.log vs the post?

Comment: console.log isn't returning anything here. I'm using Google Chrome's developer console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the following: You are submitting everything becayse of the `type="submit"` for the logout. It should be a `type="button"`.

`<input type="button" />` buttons will not submit a form - they don't do anything by default. They're generally used in conjunction with JavaScript as part of an AJAX application.

`<input type="submit" />` buttons will submit the form they are in when the user clicks on them, unless you specify otherwise with JavaScript.

```
<input name="action" value="logout" type="submit" onClick="submit_logout()">
```

to

```
<input name="action" value="logout" type="button" onClick="submit_logout()">  //type="button"
```

Comment: You sir, have a sharp eye. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

use `$('form').serialize()`

```
alert($('form[name="form"]').serialize());
```

will display all form fields

Comment: I can actually see POST data in the URL, that is not the problem. Problem is script is POSTing what I don't even intend to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
onClick="submit_logout(); return  false;"
```

Or:

```
onClick="return submit_logout();"
```

...and then `return false;` from within the `submit_logout()` function.

Or change the button to `type="button"`.

Currently because your button is `type="submit"` it causes the form to do a normal (non-Ajax) submit. Changing the type or returning false will prevent this.